# hasAttribute vs hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I ran into some jquery code which attempts to use hasOwnProperty to access an html attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">

<script>
    var e = $element.find('input')[0];
    if(!e.hasOwnProperty("placeholder")){...}
</script>
```

To my understanding, this should always be

```
if(!e.hasAttribute("placeholder")){...}
```

but what is the difference between hasAttribute and hasOwnProperty? **Are they ever equivalent?**

Comment: They are equivalent when the attribute is mirrored by a property, like some HTLM attributes are.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**hasAttribute()**

`hasAttribute()` works only for html elements and returns true if that element has the same attribute name as the given argument.

```
<div class="myClass"></div>

<script>
    document.querySelector('div').hasAttribute('class'); //true
    document.querySelector('div').hasOwnProperty('class'); //false
</script>
```

**hasOwnProperty()**

`hasOwnProperty()` works only for JavaScript objects and returns true if that object has a property with the same name as the given argument.

```
var obj = {
    myProp: "my attribute"
}

obj.hasOwnProperty("myProp") //true
obj.hasAttribute("myProp") //false
```

Some html elements can be constructed inside javascript, thats why hasOwnProperty works sometimes for it, but hasAttribute never works for javascript objects.

Comment: So `hasOwnProperty()` will work to html elements to right?

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<span medium-img>Whatever</span>
```

Javascript:

```
alert($('span').is('[medium-img]')); // Alerts true
```